# node.js Cannot read property 'length' of undefined;at Object.username

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to make a user/pass validator in node.js but I am inexperienced and receive this error:
TypeError: Cannot read property length of undefined;at Object.username (C:\Users\61468\Desktop\WebServer\validation.js:2:18)
I have tried username/password.value and tried toString but I am stuck. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const db = require("../../mongo").db(); 
const validate = require("../../validation");
const mongo = require("../../mongo");

router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
    let {username, email, password} = req.body;
    let err = validate.username(username);
    if(err) throw err;
    err = validate.password(password);
    if(err) throw err;          
    mongo.collection(users).insert({ "username": username, "password": password }).then((err, res) => {
    res.send("I just registered");
    if(err) throw err;
    })
    });

module.exports = router;


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WebServer</title>
    <script>
        function register() {
            let data = { 
            username: document.querySelector("#user").value,
            pass: document.querySelector("#pass").value,
            }
            fetch("/api/register", {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
            
            }).then((res) => {
                console.log(res.json());
            });
            
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Register:</h1>
    <input id = "user" placeholder="username">
    <input id = "pass" type = "password"placeholder="password">
    <button onclick="register()">Register</button>


</body>
</html>



function username(username) {
    if (username.length < 3) {
        return "Username cannot be less than 3 characters!";
    } else if (username.length > 15){
        return "Username cannot be longer than 15 characters!";
    }
    return "";
    
}

function password(password) {
    if (password.length < 8) {
        return "Password cannot be less than 8 characters!";
    } else if (password.length > 20){
        return "Password cannot be longer than 20 characters!";
    }
    return "";
}

module.exports = {
    username,
    password
}
```

Comment: Your argument is called the same thing as the function. Try renaming the either the function or the argument. I.e. `function validateUsername(username) …`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need Answer then you need to rename your functions
if it does not work then you need to try

add conditions in function like

```
function password(password) {
    if (password && password!=undefined && password.length < 8) {
        return "Password cannot be less than 8 characters!";
    } else if (password && password!=undefined &&password.length > 20){
        return "Password cannot be longer than 20 characters!";
    }
    return "";
}
```

like this.